# Ruth/Rus - name for convert or anyone?

Tags: names, book-of-ruth

Ruth (or Rus, depending on pronunciation and transliteration) is very common for converts, which makes sense. For non-converts (i.e., for naming a girl born to a Jewish mother) it looks like many times the English first name is Ruth but the Hebrew first name is Rachel or something else. Is there any rule (Halacha or Minhag or just a "tradition" among some groups) regarding using Ruth as a first name for someone born Jewish?

Comment: No rule. Just personal preference.

Comment: I know of women (not converts) named Rus. Most Orthodox Jews will transliterate the actual Hebrew name for the English name and not give a different name.

Comment: FWIW, My mother's (ob"m) first name was Ruth in both Hebrew and English. I know many others whose names are likewise. Mind you, that all names undergo "cultural" trends, esp. in U.S., and I would gather it's likewise in other countries. I don't know how popular Ruth has been in the past 20 - 30 years. Similarly, few girls born these days are named "Estelle" or "Claudia".

Comment: @sabbahillel Someone raised this question with me before Shavuos and pointed out that many "Ruths", including but not limited to his own mother (who passed away recently), have a different Hebrew name, unless they were converts. I was a bit surprised because I am used to "some English name that starts with 'R' but doesn't have a Hebrew equivalent being" being matched to Rachel but it doesn't make sense for "Ruth" which matches a Hebrew name - and alternatively for "Rachel" as a Hebrew name to not be translated to "Rachel" in English as that is a "normal"/popular name.

Comment: @sabbahillel "Ruth" is the transliteration of the actual Hebrew name

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes that is part of what I meant. I was also speaking about the transliteration of other Hebrew names as well. As an example *Shoshana* as the English name and not *Rose*.